# Is it possible to create myapp in GAE, but disable access from myapp.appspot.com?

Tags: google-app-engine

1. If I want to deploy anything on Google Apps, I'll have to create an application in Google App Engine, is that right? Is there a way to use FTP like in other web hosting services?
2. If I have myapp in GAE, and I already let myownsite.com to use this app. But I don't want anyone else to use this app on myapp.appspot.com, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will need to upload your application. There is no FTP access for that as far as I know, but the [GAE SDK contains a commandline tool to do that](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading.html). You can also do it from IDE.
2. There is always an associated myapp.appspot.com domain with your application, so no one will take it. But you can also use your own domain (but not for SSL!). But you cannot also block access through myapp.appspot.com, but in Java you can [create a filter that will redirect all requests to your custom domain](http://www.dev-articles.com/article/Moving-away-from-App-Engine-domains-233001). And keep in mind you cannot use naked domains (without www) in GAE.

Comment: Thanks, crystal clear now! What I'll do is to upload through GAE, use it in my own domain, then block access through Java filter.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the best solution, but you can use `self.request.headers["HOST"]` in your handler to see which domain the request was requested to and redirect the user based on that.

Comment: This is the best (and practically, only) way to do it - though you should use `self.request.host` - I'm not even sure if `self.request.headers["HOST"]` would work.

Comment: It does work because that's what I've done in my app, I didn't know about request.host before, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Thanks, since there's no GAE way to block access, I'll use your solution.